# Запретить отправку писем

Tags: php, битрикс

Как на сайте 1С-bitrix запретить отправку писем ночью в определенный промежуток времени с 21.00 по 08.00?

Данное ограничение предлогается внести только для типа почтового события SALE_STATUS_CHANGED_F

Буду благодарен, еслу кого-то есть примерный код на событие OnSaleStatusEMail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файл `\local\php_interface\init.php` (или `\bitrix\php_interface\init.php`) добавьте это

```
AddEventHandler('sale', 'OnSaleStatusEMail', 'OnSaleStatusEMailHandler');
function OnSaleStatusEMailHandler($ID, $val)
{
    $order = Bitrix\Sale\Order::load($ID);
    if ($order->getField('STATUS_ID') == 'F') {
        $dateNow = date('Y-m-d H:i'); $dateFrom = date('Y-m-d 21:00');
        $dateTo = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('+11 hours', strtotime($dateFrom)));
        if ($dateNow >= $dateFrom && $dateNow <= $dateTo) return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло